# txt files in Xamarin Forms-Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I opened up a new pcl xamarin forms project 
and I want to added a new txt file (read and write to it) my project name called mashamApp. and my android project call mashamApp.Andorid

I added a new txt file to mashamApp.Android under Assets folder called masham.txt
verifing that the build action is set to AndroidAsset
and the copy to output Directory is set to Copy always.

and under the MainActivity. cs on method OnCreate 
I have writen this lines:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("masham.txt")))
{
    string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

however when I try to run in on debug mode on a real device I am getting an error which the file is not extis

Comment: Add a check first to look for the file...

Comment: Did this code works fine in  your simulator?